# Scrapy following-sibling strong: Result not right

Tags: scrapy

I'm using scrapy to extract parts of addresses and I need help with the syntax for the. Here is the code (apologies if this is invalid code, not sure how to paste into a question correctly).

```
<div class="result">
<h3>
<a href="/provider/service/xxxxx/">service name</a>
</h3>
<p>
"blah blah"
</p>
<strong>Physical Address</strong>
    "123 address street, someplace,  somewhere"
<br/>
<strong>Postcode</strong>
    "xxx"
<br/>
<strong>District/town</strong>
    "someplace"
<br/>
<strong>Region</strong>
    "someplace bigger"
<br/>
<strong>Phone</strong>
    "xx xxx xxxx"
<br/><strong>Fax Number</strong>
    "xx xxx xxxx"
<br/>
<!--strong>Email</strong-->
    <a href="#" onclick="window.location=('mail'+'to:'+'xxxxx'+''+'@'+'xxxx.xx.xx'+''); return false;">
"xxxxx"
<strong></strong>
"xxxxx.xx.xx"
</a>
<a rel="nofollow" class="printlist-add" href="/provider/print-list/add/xxxx/">Add to print list</a>        
</div>
<hr/>
```

Here is my spider

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from test.items import TestItem

class NewSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "my_spider"

download_delay = 2

allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
start_urls = [
    "http://website.com/site1"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//*[@id="search-results"]/div')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = WebhealthItem()
        item['practice'] = site.select('h3/a/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = site.select('h3/a/@href').extract()
        item['address1'] = site.select('strong[text() = "Physical Address"]/following-sibling::text()[1]')
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

The line `item['address1'] = site.select('strong[text()="Physical Address"]/following-sibling::text()[1]')` returns a string value `[<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='strong[text()="Physical Address"]/following-sibling::text()[1]' data=u'\n\t\t\t        123 address street, someplace, some'>]`. The last few characters get clipped.

When I add `.extract()` the values show up in the cmd as `[u'\n\t\t\t        123 address street, someplace, somewhere']` but they do not appear in the output table.

I have looked for a solution, and I tried `.select('text()').extract()` but this wasn't right either.

Any help is greatly appreciated as always.

ps. advice on how to get page source code into a question on this forum would be appreciated too. Thanks

Comment: `site.select('strong[text() = "Physical Address"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract()` should work fine, or `.extract()[0].strip()` to select the 1 and only text element, without leading and atrailing whitespace, at least it works when testing locally with your HTML sample (using `sites = hxs.select('//*[@class="result"]')`)

Comment: I added `.extract()[0].strip()` and this error came up `exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range`. Any ideas?

Comment: It would mean there's no sibling text element to your targetted `strong` element. Please provide a full HTML sample of your input. Perhaps `[text() = "Physical Address"]` is too strict, `[contains(., "Physical Address")]` may be more forgiving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sample URL, I suggest you use something like this, selecting `div`s that have class "result":

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    results = hxs.select('id("search-results")/div[@class="result"]')
    items = []
    for result in results:
        item = WebhealthItem()
        item['practice'] = result.select('h3/a/text()').extract()[0]
        item['url'] = result.select('h3/a/@href').extract()[0]
        item['address1'] = map(
                unicode.strip,
                result.select('strong[text() = "Physical Address"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract()
            )[0]
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: Pasted this into my spider, it threw up `results = hxs.select('id("search-results")/div[@class="result"]'):` `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and the colon was the offending character. Truly perplexing. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Removed that colon and ran it, produced the same result - Either the values have the full xpath attached (and text is truncated), or they show in the cmd but not in the output file.

Comment: Additional info, in the cmd, it looks like this `{'address1': [u'\n\t\t\t        100 Wellington St, Freemans Bay, Auckland 1011'],`

Comment: my bad, ':' was because I tested with `for result in hxs.select('id("search-results")/div[@class="result"]'):`

Comment: well `.extract()` always returns a list, that can be empty. If you want only the first element in this list, you can add an `[0]` after each `.extract()`. Additionally you may want to strip the whitespace characters at the beginning, so you can do `item['address1'] = map(unicode.strip, result.select('strong[text() = "Physical Address"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract())[0]`

Comment: How do you generate your output file?

Comment: That last line of code that you posted was the answer. Fantastic. I am outputting to csv fyi.

Answer (score 1):

```
def caiqinghua_array_string_strip(array_string):
if(array_string == []):
    return ''
else:
    #print 'item::: ', array_string[0].strip()
    string = array_string[0].replace('\\r\\n', '')
    return string.strip()

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//*[@id="search-results"]/div')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = WebhealthItem()
        item['practice'] = site.select('h3/a/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = site.select('h3/a/@href').extract()
        address = site.select('strong[text() = "Physical Address"]/following-sibling::text()[1]')
        item['address1'] = caiqinghua_array_string_strip(address)
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Hope it can help you. By the way, suggest you change items = [] to items_list = [] or other, because the items is a key word of the scrapy and may be conflict in the future.