# Assigning a heading which varies by value of XPath, in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to assign values obtained from an XPath under a heading whose label would be derived from another XPath. I will need to do this as the structure of the website I'm scraping changes from one page to the next.

An example is as follows:

```
PAGE 1:

Dog Age: 7
Dog Gender: M

PAGE 2:

Dog Gender: M
```

Running my code on both pages would yield the following result in my output:

> Page Number     Dog
>   Age     Dog Gender
>   1                          7
>                  M
>   2                          M

This is the code currently:

```
def parse_listing_page(self,response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    item = response.meta['item']
    item['dog age'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="features"]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/span/text()').extract()
    item['dog gender'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="features"]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/span/text()').extract()
    return item
```

I would like to be able to make the 'dog age' based on what the true preceding heading is for the value. The heading's Xpath is as follows:

```
hxs.select('//*[@id="features"]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/text()').extract()
```

How would I be able to incorporate this into my code?

Comment: Not familiar with Scrapy, but I should think you could select each line of the form `Dog Attribute: Value` using an XPath query, and then parse it in Python?

Comment: Thanks for your response halfer. I'm just hoping there's another way of doing it.

I thought about creating standard titles such as "title1" for whatever the first title is (e.g. it will parse "Dog Age" for page 1 and "Dog Gender" for page 2) and doing the same for the value with "titleValue1"

Comment: Do you mean the HTML for the scrape target is under your control? If so, why not connect to the database directly rather than scraping?

Comment: No the HTML isn't in my control at all so I won't be able to connect to the database

Comment: Alright, well do it my way for now (use XPath to get the line and use Python to split it up) and then improve if you can find a better XPath expression. I would imagine there is a "tag contents begins with" function.

Comment: Thanks Halfer. The XPath for the title (E.G. "Dog Age") and the value (E.G. 7) are actually separate. For the time being, I am pulling them out separately (in separate fields) and then using Excel to assign the value under the appropriate title.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the `html` of the website, i can't give you a specific code example, but i believe `following-sibling` is what you're after. Something like what is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309960/scrapy-parsing-list-items-onto-separate-lines) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262895/scrapy-following-sibling-strong-result-not-right).